# click event to update the gridview in ASP

Tags: asp.net

It convenient to do the query by :

```
<asp: AccessDataSource >
```

I wish to update the query string and update the result by a click event.

```
<asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="To Inquiry"
       OnClick="doInquiry" 
       runat="server"/>
```

How I can achieve to update the query string and do the query in  in the "doInquiry" function; BUT, still using the following useful code.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Northwind.MDB" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categories]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you generate the HTML via the markup and the behavior is different from what you expect, check the generated HTML in your browser. You intended to set the `onclick` attribute of an HTML tag, however, [OnClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property pointing to the server-side method, which manages the server-side click event. You intended to use the [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx) property.